# ResizeEvent is called indefintely when fitInView is called (QGraphicsScene)

Tags: qgraphicsview

I have this weird problem.

I create my scene inside a QGraphicsView extended class like so:

```
scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
this->setScene(scene);
this->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop|Qt::AlignLeft);
showRect.setCoords(0,0,sceneWidth,sceneHeight);
```

However. This same class has reimplemented the resizeEvent Method according to documentation:

```
void ConversationView::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *e){
    //Q_UNUSED(e);
    this->fitInView(showRect,Qt::KeepAspectRatioByExpanding);
    qWarning() << e->size();
}
```

Now I add a box the scene and nothing happens. But when I start resizing the window, there comes a point where I stop and the program hangs and I keep seing the sizing message, forever and ever with very very small variations on its size:

```
QSize(1342, 190) 
QSize(1356, 190) 
QSize(1342, 190) 
QSize(1356, 190)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. Instead of redefining the ConversationView's resize event (which extends from QGraphicsView), I redefined the containing Widget's resizeEvent (in this case a class based of a QDialog).

With the exact same parameters this made the problem go away.